# pipe of "ps -e", "tee" and "head" behaves strange

Tags: bash, macos

I meant to use the following command to grep the "zsh" process with header. But this command only showed the header and then exited. The `grep` didn't run.  I can do this task by other ways but I want to understand what happened here.  The interesting thing is that the pipe works as expected if other command like `ls` replaces `ps -e`. In fact, the pipe works even with `ps` (without `-e`). The pipe also works if `head` is replaced by another `grep`. Seemingly, there are some interesting interactions between `ps -e`, `head` and `tee` in this pipe. Any explanation? I ran the commands in MacOS-iterm2 and zsh.  Thanks.

```
 ps -e|tee >(head -n 1) >(grep "zsh") >/dev/null
```

the command above produces the following incorrect output: only header is shown, grep didn't run.

```
PID TTY           TIME CMD
```

The correct output can be generated by the following command:

```
ps -e|awk 'FNR==1{print};/zsh/{print}'
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1658 ttys000    0:00.30 -zsh
 2817 ttys001    0:00.49 /bin/zsh -i
12890 ttys002    0:00.26 -zsh
13332 ttys003    0:00.23 -zsh
13469 ttys004    0:00.19 /bin/zsh -i
```

Update: The problem is indeed in the `tee` shipped with MacOS. As @OndrejK. pointed out in the comments below, `tee` from GNU works as expected.

Comment: Is there any other relevant output? I would guess that after `head` finishes reading after one line and exits, `tee` may quite on a closed output / broken pipe. But if I try your line, it would not do that (by default) on my system (read: I cannot reproduce the behavior you are seeing), unless I told it `--output-error=exit` (which I am wondering if that could differ on your host). Needless to say, if was trying to pick these lines off, I'd probably go with `ps -e | sed -ne '1p;/zsh/p'`, it seems simpler to me.

Comment: @OndrejK Interesting. So the pipe of `ps -e`, `tee` and `head` works for you? If so, I wonder in which env you ran the command. I ran the command in macOS-iterm2 and  zsh. Maybe different env behaves differently?

Comment: @sgu Yes, there could be also different flavors of the tools (with different default behavior). I tried that on Slackware 15.0 (that also means largely GNU and not BSD tools) using bash. So I take it, no additional output was present? Why I ask, with `--output-error=exit` it would fail after the first line being printed, but with broken pine message on the descriptor used for redirection to `head`.

Comment: @OndrejK. Yes, you are right! The problem indeed is in the `tee` command shipped with MacOS. I tried the tee from  gnu-coreutils, with `--output-error=warn`, I got the expected output. However, `tee` shipped with MacOS doesn't provide such option. Still, it is strange that why the command works for `ps` without `-e` option. Why no broken pipe in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Ondrej K. nailed it in a comment: `head` is reading just the first line it receives from `tee`, then exiting, so when `tee` tries to write the second line to that pipe, it gets an error (probably actually a SIGPIPE signal) and exits without writing the rest of `ps's` output.

I was able to reproduce this problem under both macOS and Raspbian, using both zsh and bash as my shell. I was able to get the full output by replacing `head` with something that reads (but doesn't output) the rest of the input from `tee`. Here's an example:

```
% ps -e|tee >(head -n 1) >(grep "zsh") >/dev/null
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
% ps -e|tee >(head -n 1; cat>/dev/null) >(grep "zsh") >/dev/null
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
13127 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
13353 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
% ps -e|tee >(sed -n '1p') >(grep "zsh") >/dev/null             
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
13127 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
```

In the second version above, adding `cat>/dev/null` after `head` lets it consume (and discard) the rest of the input after `head` exits. In the third, `sed -n '1p'` reads its entire input, but only prints the first line.

Note that the result here will depend on things like buffer sizes and the timing of various events, so it may be inconsistent between different environments or even vary randomly under apparently consistent conditions. I suspect the reason it works with `ps` (without the `-e` option) is that it doesn't produce enough output to trigger the problem: `tee` may be able to forward the entire output from `ps` before `head` gets around to exiting.

EDIT: At least in my environments, adding a delay after `head` exits prevents the problem:

```
% ps -e|tee >(head -n 1; sleep 1) >(grep "zsh") >/dev/null      
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8002 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
 8164 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
```

This means it's timing-limited, rather than buffer-limited. But if the output from `ps` were big enough, it'd run into buffer limits at some point, and the output would be truncated no matter what delays were inserted.